# Source code for Android location provider packages

Tags: android, network-programming, android-source

I am trying to find android source code for its `network_provider` implementation. So far, I traced into `com.android.server.location.LocationProviderProxy` and found it loads packages from a list of location provider package names. The package name is supposed to be in 
`com.android.internal.R.array.config_locationProviderPackageNames`, which I can not find in `com.android.internal.R.array` on [the Android Javadoc website.](http://www.androidjavadoc.com/)

Where are those packages and their source codes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The package names are defined in [/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/config.xml](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/config.xml/):

```
<string-array name="config_locationProviderPackageNames" translatable="false">
    <!-- The standard AOSP fused location provider -->
    <item>com.android.location.fused</item>
</string-array>
```

And if you're looking for the source for the fused location provider itself, you can find that on grepcode [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/com/android/location/fused/FusedLocationProvider.java) or googlesource [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/6fa9ad4afcd762aea519ff61811386c23d18ddb2/packages/FusedLocation/src/com/android/location/fused/FusedLocationProvider.java).

If you're looking for the network location provider, it seems the source code for that is no longer available. Quoting a [message by Mike Lockwood](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-platform/10Yr0r2myGA/mUm_tRNfomwJ) from the Google android team:

> The network location provider used to be in the open source, but
>   has since been removed.  We did this because we want the core android
>   framework to be independent of any Google's services.  We were also
>   concerned that someone might ship a phone that uses network location
>   without informing the user of its existence.  Since it does
>   communicate the user's location to our servers, we want to ensure that
>   it is strictly an opt-in service and the users are made aware of our
>   privacy guidelines.  So now we only make NetworkLocation.apk available
>   in binary form to partners that agree to follow our guidelines on how
>   it is used.

As for finding old versions of the network location provider, I would suggest a google search for `NetworkLocationProvider.java`. I didn't see anything that looked particularly authoritative, but the first result was from [netmite.com](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/location/java/com/android/internal/location/NetworkLocationProvider.java).

If you're specifically interested in the code that communicates with the Google Location Service backend, though, you should probably look at the `LocationMasfClient` class, which you can see [here](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/location/java/com/android/internal/location/LocationMasfClient.java).

Comment: That is helpful. I am still unable to find the code which does the actual communicating with Google location server and process the returned data to get a location fix. Could you point to the direction?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is in the network location provider which is not open source. I've updated the answer with more details.

Comment: Very helpful. "It is used to be open source". How can I find a copy of its "old" open sourced version?

Comment: Updated answer again with some more links.